# ElasticSeach combine multi_match and match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ES 7, I want to search over multi fields, but on this field (`title`) must be shown firstly if it matches exactly. For now I tried :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "titre": {
                                    "query": "test",
                                    "boost": "20"
                                 }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "fields": ["titre", "description^4", "subtitle^3"],
                                "query": "test",
                                "type": "most_fields"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I would like to order the `match_phrase` before other results.

The idea is the user type the exact phrase of a title, this result will appear before other based on multi_match.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional boost to the `match_phrase` query?

Comment: Yes, I tried even a 30 boost, I will update my question

Comment: I think you're missing an opening curly brace in your `match_phrase` query, though, do you confirm?

Comment: I putted the real json, sorry I made mistake copy / pasting

Comment: What I would try is to move the `multi_match` query to `bool/must` and keep the boosted version of `match_phrase` inside `bool/should`. can you try it?

Comment: @Val it worked with the boost, thanks ! the error was somewhere else, I got ID's from result and then, I used a SQL query like `WHERE id IN (32, 231, 3290)`, but this messed up the order ... Didn't know ! I will close my question